# Modifying Windows Firewall to send ICMP unreachable

Tags: security, firewall, windows-11, windows-firewall, nmap

Can I modify my windows Firewall to send ICMP unreachable rather than drop packets? or this is something that is not available in MS windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Windows Firewall drops or accepts packets. Its job is to do so quickly and efficiently.  You will need a 3rd party app to do what you want.

Comment: Any recommendations?

Comment: I have never seen anything that will integrate with FIrewall.  You likely need to write a complete firewall replacement.   It is generally up to the receiver to figure out their error.

Comment: ICMP unreachable comes from a router. Firewalls drop unauthorized traffic silently. A response to a packet equals confirmation that the system is up 'n' running, which in itself already unnecessarily compromises system security.

Comment: You didn't get it, when you set the firewall to send unreachable most of scanning tools will end the scanning from the first port because its unreachable.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve. We don't "get" what you haven't told us, and it seems you're trying to solve Problem X by trying to change how the Windows Firewall behaves, when it is not clear that is the actual solution. Use the Edit button and tell us Problem X and we may be able to get you a better solution overall.

Comment: It's not really a problem, im just playing with the win firewall any way, x is as you said I want to change my window firewall behavior

Comment: That's a ping scan. it will expect ICMP responses, but port scanning occurs on TCP/UDP, neither of which use ICMP. but I'll bow out and clean up your thread

Comment: UDP for example there is 2 situation first is the Application layer protocol ex)DNS sec is ICMP there is alot of details we can discuss.
thanks for trying Frank, really appreciate it 

Answer (score 0):

there is no feature that’s available with the built in Windows firewall. I need a third party service to accomplish this.